# JavaScript: Create Function that Returns Function in which Returned Function Invokes Passed Function

Tags: javascript, function, callback, iterator, higher-order-functions

I am trying to create a function "thrice" that returns another function.

I have the following code below:

```
const thrice = (inputFunc) => {
  return inputFunc()
}

let eight;

eight = thrice(() => {
  return 8;
});

const value = eight();
value
```

My expectation is that value will equal: 8.  It should equal 8 based on my test spec.

But when I run my code, it returns: `TypeError: eight is not a function`

What am I doing wrong?  My hunch is I should do `return inputFunc` inside the thrice function.  But I conceptually don't understand why.

Comment: `const thrice = f => x => f(f(f(x)))` would apply function `f` to `x` three times... I'm guessing you need something closer to that. Ie, `const add1 = x => x + 1; const add3 = thrice(add1); add3(10); // =>13`.

Comment: Your main issue is that you are calling the function in `thrice` rather than just returning it. Change to `return inputFunc` and it will work as expected.

Comment: @Mark: I think I understand; I'm invoking the function inside thrice when I should just be returning the full function which can later be called

Comment: @PineNuts0 Alternatively, `return  x => inputFunc(x)`

Comment: There are just two functions declared (`=>`) but you call three (`()`). Which one of the calls you remove does not matter, you could also add a function, but that depends on your usecase.

Comment: `const thrice = fn => fn;` would cause `value` to be `8`. But then you might as well `const eight = () => 8;` instead of `const eight = thrice(() => 8);` since it's a no-op.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that

```
thrice(() => {
  return 8;
});
```

is not a function but a function call so `eight` equals to 8.
so to fix this :

```
eight = ()=> thrice(() => {
  return 8;
});
// or

eight =function(){ thrice(() => {
  return 8;
});};
```